# How to work with empty arrays in python just like MATLAB?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, append, empty-list

I'm implementing a code from MATLAB to Python. I have to define some empty arrays, assigning some values to them and make them empty in the body of code.

Let's say my code in MATLAB looks like this :

```
s1 = []

s1 = [A.T]
```

`s1` would be equate to an empty in MATLAB again for next iterations (`s1 = []`) .
I tried to write this in python like below:

```
s1 = []
s1.append(A.T)
s11 = np.vstack(s1)
```

and I'm able to use `s11` instead of `s1` in my code. However, for the next iterations, I should empty the `s11` and so I wrote it like this: `s11 = []`.

Doing this will raise an error when I get to this line `s11 = np.vstack(s1)` since I have equated `s11` to a None object (`[]`) at the previous iteration.

In summary, I was wondering how I can create an empty array in python, assign or append values to it and then make it empty again? 
`s1` is the input of a function and I must have the ability to make it empty in different iterations.
In MATLAB it's so straightforward without any trouble.

Any comments would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I read your question, it looks like you are using lists. It is a bit confusing since array on python are something else then lists.

At first you already mentioned an awnser to your question already:

```py
A = [[1,2],[3,4]]
s1 = []
s1.append(A)

s11 = np.vstack(s1)
s11 = []
```

One very import thing: In the moment as you use np.vstack your list is changing to type numpy.array. So you can't use `del s11[:]` any longer.

If this is not working please give us more informations about `A.T` maybe there is some datatype problem.

One thing left: You are writing about an error that is raising. It is very difficult for us to magicly read your errormessage over distance from your computer (and it is illegal).

These two things: the error message and the complete data from your minimal example are necessary for us to help you.

Comment: Hi, The point is that using s11 = [] will raise an error in the next iterations. We defined the s11, instead of s1, to append A to it. In the second iteration, s11 is just like s1 and is empty so we can not write s11 = np.vstack(s1). and also we can not define a new variable like s111 again and again.

Comment: I still don't know what error this is raising. `s11=[]` is just defining the variable as empty list. since I also dont know what A is (is it a skalar, another list or and np.array) It is really hard to reproduce your problem.